# Navigating from one screen to other is not working in react native using wix react native navigation V2

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using wix react native navigation v2 for navigating from one screen to the other screen.When a button in the first screen clicked the following code runs

```
    Navigation.push(this.props.componentId,{
      component: {
        name: 'example.myappname.PushedScreen',
        passProps: {
          text: 'Pushed screen'
        },
       options: {
         topBar: {
           title: {
             text: 'Pushed screen title'
           }
         }
       }
     }
   });
```

But not navigating to the second screen

Comment: Have you registered the views correctly? https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Usage?id=registercomponentscreenid-generator

Comment: Check if componentId is not null

Comment: We need more info, can't give you an answer just based on this code.